# Disable button based on cell db status

Tags: php, mysqli

My code is not working. I'm trying to disable a button based on data from a table cell. This is an example of my table.

```
 Table A (tickets)
*----------------*
| id | repair_id |
|  1 |  10, 11   |
|  2 |    12     |
*----------------*
```

and my current code:

```
<?php
    $sql =  "SELECT repair_id FROM tickets WHERE t_id =".$ticket_id." ";
    $sql .= "AND repair_id REGEXP ',' ";

        $box_check = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        $box_empty = mysqli_fetch_array($box_check);
            if(count($box_empty) == 0) {
                echo "<button class='btn btn-primary' disabled='disabled' name='add_box'>Add Box</button>";
            } else {
                echo "<button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' name='add_box'>Add Box</button>";
            }
?>
```

My goal is to allow the box to be active so long as there is more than 1 `id` in `repair_id`.

Currently the box is disabled or enabled on all depending on if I set `if(count($box_empty) == true/false/0/1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, `... REGEXP ', '` selects only those rows that have more than one repair ids. Based on your question,

> My goal is to allow the box to be active so long as there is more than 1 id in repair_id.

Use a simple `SELECT` query without `REGEX` and make use of [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function to check whether the `repair_id` column contains more than one repair ids or not, and then display the buttons accordingly, like this:

```
$sql =  "SELECT repair_id FROM tickets WHERE t_id =".$ticket_id;

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if(strpos($row['repair_id'], ",") === false) {
        echo "<button class='btn btn-primary' disabled='disabled' name='add_box'>Add Box</button>";
    } else {
        echo "<button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' name='add_box'>Add Box</button>";
    } 
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. the buttons do not show up at all.

Comment: @cpt-crunchy Do `echo $result->num_rows;` and check how many rows you're getting from the SELECT query. Also, paste your code on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/index.php) and give me it's link here.

Comment: I added the pastebin link plus I added the echo with no results. [HERE](http://pastebin.com/aHFbd7XQ)

Comment: I found my issue. I had a previous query I was using and i didn't list the ticket_id value within the query. This code worked perfectly. Thanks @Rajdeep